# uiview drop shadow transparency issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` with a "dropshadow" and a `tableView` below it. The problem that I can't figure out is how to make the "dropshadow" transparent so that `tableView` and details below can be seen through the shadow (see image below). I tried playing with the opacity and radius but it's not working.

Here is my code to create the drop shadow:

```
postDetails.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
postDetails.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 3.0f);
postDetails.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
postDetails.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
postDetails.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

EDIT:
I think what is also contributing to the issue is the the layout.
it is:

- UIView (superview)
- UITextview (subview of UIView)
- UITableView (subview of UIView)

The text should be able to be seen through the shadow for a cleaner look.

[image]

Comment: What's the Y co-ordinate and height size of your UITextField, compared to the Y coordinate of the UITableview?

Comment: a decade later, you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884

Answer (score 2):

The way I was able to do this is through the .shouldRasterize property.

1. I create a view called shadow view.
2. Make sure it is *not* transparent in any way.
3. Configure the shadow in code:

   ```
   UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_viewShadow.bounds];
   _viewShadow.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
   _viewShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
   _viewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
   _viewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
   _viewShadow.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
   _viewShadow.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
   ```
4. Now we can make our shadow view transparent!

   ```
   _viewShadow.alpha = 0.8f;
   ```
5. At this point you should see a transparent view where the drop shadow only shows outside of the borders of the image.
6. Lastly, we display our content *on top* of the shadow view so it is not effected by the alpha changes.

I basically use the .shouldRasterize property to render the layer before any alpha-blending is done with the parent layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
postDetails.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.5 alpha:1].CGColor;
postDetails.layer. shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

Comment: this didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Drop shadow for the textView will not solve your problem since it wont extend to the full length of tableView. Instead of this you can put a transparent view to the top of tableView. Add a temporary view with background transparent background color during editing and remove after the editing done

```
self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: Not a bad idea but then you don't get the shadow effect.. just a dark bar.

Comment: What you have done? You have add this overlayView as a sub view the tableView area

Comment: You can search for transparent view or blurred view in iOS. Anyway drop shadow will not serve you much iam sure

Comment: I created a transparent view and added it as a subview below the uitextview, although it is transparent.. you dont get the same look as a shadow..

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
postDetails.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]; // set color as you want
postDetails.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f; // set Opacity as you want
postDetails.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0); // set it as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an UIImageView to provide the shadow. I created an image of 1 pixel wide, by 12 pixels high. The image was black, but the alpha was a gradient from 0.5 at the top to 0.0 at the bottom eg. RGBA 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5 -> 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0 - I then placed the UIImageView just below the view needing the shadow, and stretched it horizontally across the width of the view.
I have also used this when I needed to change the intensity of the shadow when a scroll view below is scrolling, by changing the UIImageView.alpha value